# view es6 module export/import dependencies

Tags: webpack, es6-modules

I have a web project with over 60 es6 modules that use `export` and `import`. I am looking for a way to graph, or map out, the relationships between the modules. I am looking for circular dependencies and opportunities for code splitting and just visualizing the project in general.

I thought `npm ls` would answer my question but it seems to list everything in node_modules/ (which I don't care about) and none of my own modules. I also looked at [dependo](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dependo). But neither got close to what I want (or else I don't understand how to use them).

Answer (score 3):

[Madge](https://github.com/pahen/madge) does pretty much what I was looking for. It creates a nice svg graph of dependencies. Install:

> npm -dev install madge

and to create a svg graphic (Ubuntu):

> sudo apt-get install graphviz

and then run:

```
node_modules/.bin/madge --image graph.svg src/index.js
```

Here is an example (svg saved as png)

[image: mage graphic output]